# choose k points, which are non neighboring, among m points on circle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are m points on the circle. Choose k points among those m points. And k points should not neighbor each other.

My Idea is... there are :

- k numbers of black stones
- n-k numbers of white stones
- place white stones on the circle (n-k-1)! b.c placing on the circle.
- And remove orders on white stone by dividing (n-k-1)! by (n-k)!
- And place black stones between white stones. ${n-k \choose k}$

So my answer is $\frac{1}{n-k}  *$ $n-k \choose k$
But answer on my textbook is $\frac{n}{n-k}  *$ $n-k \choose k$
I think I should multiply my answer by n b.c n points is already fixed on the circle and I didn't considered it when I place white stones on it, so I should multiply it by n.

Please give me your feedback or other solutions!

Comment: Is $m=n$?  If $(m,k)=(2,1)$ then there are two choices, clearly.  But your expression gives $\frac 11\times \binom 11=1$.  So go through your argument line by line in this case to spot the error.